# How to update the data of a particular column in SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I was updating the values of columns to 0.00 using below query

```
update table name set column name = '0.00'
```

I did this for many columns but I also accidentally updated one wrong column to 0.00 which I was not suppose to do. now I want the data back for this column, I have backup in Excel file but don't know how to update only this particular column. 
Please help

Comment: It's the same syntax that you already have.  If you updated the wrong column, and have the data you want to restore to that column, it's just another update statement.  (Side note: Taking a backup and restoring from that backup is generally better than building a second script to try to un-do the first script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the number of rows affected you could try something like putting the following formula in cell `C2` of your Excel table:

```
="UPDATE tbl_name SET col_name=" & B2 & " WHERE id=" & A2
```

assuming that in your Excel table the `id`s for each record can be found in column `A` and the original values in column `B`. If you then copy the formula down until you have the whole table covered you should end up with a command batch of `UPDATE` commands which you should **check carefully at first** and then possibly apply on your database to revover the old values.